# Issues with Compiz Config Setting Manager and XFCE 4

Tags: compiz, xfce

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 and XFCE4, but when I want to configure Compiz with CCSM, the plugins that I selected don't save when I close the program. In Unity it works perfectly, but I want to use compiz in XFCE4.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! The file `Default.ini` in `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig` was owned by root and not writable by my user account. I changed the permissions for all users and my configs saved again.

Comment: Bad solution. You should `sudo chown $USER ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig` rather than giving write permissions to o.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this guide:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-set-up-compiz-in-xubuntu-1210-or.html

Comment: I followed this guide, but the problem is the Compiz Config Settings Manager don't save the configuration in this desktop enviroment, only in Unity. :/

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 32bit and I've followed this guide and everything is working fine for me without any problems. Perhaps if you use a 64bit installation maybe there are some differences.